# to implement stack of strings in C

Tags: c, data-structures, stack

I want to implement a stack of strings wherein every element of a stack represents a string. For example
I input names of people as elements. I have written the following code but the display is not working.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define max 5
struct stack{
    int top;
    char *stack[100];
};
typedef struct stack stack;

void push(struct stack *s)
{
    char element[20];
    if (s->top == max-1)
    {
        printf("Stack is full\n");
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        s->top+=1;
        printf("Enter the element to be pushed\n");
        scanf("%s",element);
        for(int i=0;element[i]!='/0';i++)
        *(s->stack[s->top])=element;
    }
}

void pop(struct stack *s)
{
    if (s->top == -1)
    {
        printf("Stack is empty\n");
        return;
    }
    else
    {        printf("The element deleted is %s\n",*(s->stack[s->top]));
        s->top-=1;
    }
}

void display(struct stack *s)
{
    if (s->top == -1)
    {
        printf("Stack is empty\n");
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        for (int i=0;i<=s->top;i++)
        {
            printf("%s\n",*(s->stack[i]));
        }
    }
}
int main()
{
    struct stack s;
    s.top=-1;
    int ch;
    for(;;)
    {
    printf("Enter your choice\n1.Push\n2.Pop\n3.Display\n4.Exit\n");
    scanf("%d",&ch);
    switch (ch)
    {
        case 1:
            push(&s);
            break;
        case 2:
            pop(&s);
            break;
        case 3:
            display(&s);
            break;
        case 4:
            goto a;
            break;
        default:
            printf("Invalid choice");
            break;
    }
    }
    a:
    return 0;
}
```

This is an example of the expected terminal :
Enter your choice
1.Push
2.Pop
3.Display
4.Exit
1
Enter the element to be pushed
john
Enter your choice
1.Push
2.Pop
3.Display
4.Exit
1
Enter the element to be pushed
maddy
Enter your choice
1.Push
2.Pop
3.Display
4.Exit
3
The elements are:
john
maddy

Comment: `*(s->stack[i])` looks like one de-reference too many. Compile with strict standard settings and pay attention to compiler warnings/errors.

Comment: It's not exactly the problem, but when you look at where the code is copying letters hoping to save them,, consider also adding a terminating `\0` to make a "C string".

Comment: *... but the display is not working.* What does *not working* mean?

Comment: ` goto a;` means `break;` will never execute. Rename `a` to a meaningful name if you are going to use `goto`.

Comment: `scanf("%s",element);` can overflow `char element[20];`. use `scanf("%19s", element);`

Comment: `element[i]!='/0'` --> `element[i]!='\0'`

Comment: Your `push` and `pop` functions are not really useful. In any real world use case you will need to provide the new value to your `push` function and you must return a value from your `pop` function. Asking for input withing `push` function does not make any sense beyond some homework task.

Answer (score 1):

I looked only at the `push()` part of your code.

You have `char *stack[100];` which is an array of 100 character pointers.
You need `char stack[5][20];` which an array of 5 strings of 20 character each.

To save the strings in the stack you need to change the copy part of your code:

```
for(int i=0; element[i]!='\0'; i++)
  s->stack[s->top][i] = element[i];
```

This copies the string character for character onto the stack.
`strncpy()` would be a better way of doing this.

```
strncpy(s->stack[s->top], element, 20);
```

Look at all the comments on your question as well for other problems and [code smells](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell).
There a still still some other problems remaining.